# Chosing correct way to Submit a Form In jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation

"As far as I did some research I have found these following approaches to submit a form using jQuery. Can you please let me know which one is more accurate way to submit a form than the others?

1- Targeting the Form Directly

```
 $( "form" ).on( "submit", function( e ) {
       e.preventDefault();
   });
```

2- Targeting a Button in Form

```
$( "#abtn" ).on( "click", function( e ) {
       e.preventDefault();
 });
```

3- Targeting Submit Button in the Form

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    // code here
     return false;
  });
```

In case of using `e.preventDefault();` where is the best to put in? 
At the beginning of the form submitting or at the end?

Comment: note that #2 and #3 target specific elements (of which there should (aka must) only be 1 on the page, but #1 could affect multiple forms if there is more than 1 on the page

Comment: What do you mean bu "submit a form on jQuery"? Do you want to get the form data and send it through AJAX?

Comment: @ SamuraiDio, yes that is exactly what I want to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your situation, but I'd say that the best way is:

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Why? Because a user could press enter rather than clicking, or there could be something else that autofills the forms and then submits it.

With the code above you are sure to intercept those cases as well.

As for `e.preventDefault();`, it doesn't matter where you put it as long as it's inside the event callback function.

Comment: Sute. But will be best to limit the query for the form id `$("form#form_id")`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using **[Malsup's jQuery form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)** as it seems to be the plugin you are looking for from what I've read in your comments, which say you want to submit the form in ajax, not just preventing the default form submit behaviour.